# Add custom filtering for lightning component

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-community, community-builder

I am developing a salesforce community with lightning web components. First, I drag and dropped **Tab Structure**. Then it shows a config window as follows.

[image]

There is an **Add** button to add multiple tabs. I am creating a custom component and I can configure only String, Boolean properties. I need to Select Object name from drop down. Further I should be able to add filter fields with filtering values.

I am stuck at this and was unable to find any resource.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @sanketkumar I was able to add list of object names. I was unable to add list of fields. For that I need some thing similar to above screenshot.